# How do I allow a user to modify a list in my code?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2015

I have an assignment in my computer science class to create a list of course, add variable to them (i.e. name, prefix, credit hours), have those courses displayed to the cmd and then allow a user to add or remove a course.

I already have the lists of courses, but I have been unable to write the correct code to allow a user to add or remove an item from the list. I can collect variables from a user to add a course but I don't know how to actually use that data to create one. Here's my code, I'm sorry if it's messy; I've had to play around quite a bit to try things and I'm also very new to this.

I need to know how to allow the user to delete  and or add a course to the list. My code below does not work, it just keeps iterating across the list into the display no matter what i enter in.

This is the code I wrote to remove an item. It is supposed to hold the users input as an integer and relay that to the if statement that corresponds the index position with the integer value.

```
        public static void Remove(int index)
        {
            List<Course> courseList = new List<Course>();
            Course c1 = new Course();
            Course c2 = new Course(2010, 3, "TCOM", "Technical Writing");
            Course c3 = new Course(2345, 3, "Math", "Discrete Mathematics");
            Course c4 = new Course(2332, 3, "Math", "Probablility and Data Analysis");

            courseList.Add(c1);
            courseList.Add(c2);
            courseList.Add(c3);
            courseList.Add(c4);

            courseList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
```

This code block is supposed to add a course. It appropriately asks the user for variable and stores them, but I don't know how to apply them and add it to the list.

```
        public static void Add()
        {
            List<Course> courseList = new List<Course>();
            Course c1 = new Course();
            Course c2 = new Course(2010, 3, "TCOM", "Technical Writing");
            Course c3 = new Course(2345, 3, "Math", "Discrete Mathematics");
            Course c4 = new Course(2332, 3, "Math", "Probability and Data Analysis");

            courseList.Add(c1);
            courseList.Add(c2);
            courseList.Add(c3);
            courseList.Add(c4);
        }

        private static void ProcessChoice(int choice)
        {
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a course to delete, with the first course being 0.");

                if (choice == 0)
                {
                    Remove(0);
                }

                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    Remove(1);
                }

                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    Remove(2);
                }

                if (choice == 3)
                {
                    Remove(3);
                }

                if (choice == 4)
                {
                    Remove(4);
                }

                if (choice == 5)
                {
                    Remove(5);
                }

            }

            if (choice == 2)
            {
                Console.Write("What is the course number? ");
                int coursenum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("What is the prefix of your course? ");
                string pref = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("What is the name of your course? ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("How many credit hours is the course worth? ");
                int crehours = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                List<Course> courseList = new List<Course>();
                Course c5 = new Course(coursenum, crehours, pref, name);
                courseList.Add(c5);

                Console.WriteLine(); // Once again to add space.
            }
```

Comment: The problem is that your functions do not share the data. The scope of your lists are on method (function) level and not on class level (shared between functions). Look at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx

Comment: Also removing the course item by its index will probably crash your program

Comment: `if (choice == 1)
            { ...
                if (choice == 0)
                {` you will never get this choice==0 or anything but the ==1

Comment: There is too much code here, and not a specific enough problem statement. _"i have been unable to write the correct code"_ is not a useful problem statement. Please simplify the code so that you have provided [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does, and how that is different from what you want. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @DavidKron I have tried to move my list to be just inside the class level and it doesn't transfer through to my methods. I have also tried to create an accessor for this reason and it also did not work. My accessor was simply public List<Course> courseList { get return Course; }. Was that the correct form or should i have tried something else. As I said I am very new to writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Like *David Kron* said, your methods cannot access your `List`. Use a `field` to store the contents of the `List`, e.g.:

```
public class X
{
    private List<Course> courseList = new List<Course>();
}
```

This will create a new instance of `List<Course>` that you can access in the instance of your class. You can add items to the list with [`Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) and remove items with [`Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx).

The if-statements in `ProcessChoice()` are unnecessary. You can simply compare the user's input with the data in your list. You can iterate over the list with [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).